# How to make Pull Requests on a wordpress.org plugin?

Tags: plugins, repository, plugin-repository

How can I submit pull request to other's plugin, which is hosted at **wordpress.org**?

Comment: sorry, but the only people that might be relevant to this question are the wordpress.org support, and even then, plugin authors might not care about getting and handling PRs

Comment: No, the wordpres.org svn repositories are not for development and there are no plans to change this. So you have to ask on support forum, if the plugin is on github or search for it on github.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the wordpres.org SVN repositories are not for development and there are no plans to change this. So you either have to ask on support forum, or if the plugin is on an open GIT repository search for it on GitHub.

Comment: "wordpres.org SVN repositories are not for development" is simply not true

Comment: @MarkKaplun "Unlike Git, our SVN repository is a release repository, not a development one" https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2017/04/05/reminder-how-svn-wordpress-org-works/

Comment: very well, stupid, but whatever.

Answer (score 5):

WordPress.org repository uses SVN, not Git, so there are no pull requests.

Only users with contributor status can access plugins to commit changes. Each plugin has one contributor by default, but more contributors can be allowed to each plugin.

Some plugins are developed on GitHub, and only released on WordPress.org when ready.